# Page titles disapeared from chrome tabs after upgrading to 13.10

Tags: google-chrome, 13.10

After upgrading my Ubuntu to 13.10, Chrome is not showing titles of websites in tabs (only favicons). Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: It's a [reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1222718).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by [installing Mir](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mir/Installing). It occasionally appears in Mir too, but all you have to do is switch Mir on and off again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by opening "Software and Updates", clicking on the "Additional Drivers" tab.  It showed a proprietary driver being used for my video from fglrx (I have the Radeon HD 6310).  I changed it to X.org X Server driver, which is open source and it started working again after reboot.  Hope this helps!